# In Vue CLI, the defined variable inside the data property does not work, when used with this.VariableName

Tags: javascript, variables, vue.js, fabricjs, vue-cli

#### Problem

I want to use a variable in `mounted()` and `methods:` and thus defined it in the `data()` property inside `export default {}`. Although there is no error logged, it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

#### Setup

I am running on **vue version 3.9.3** and **npm version 6.10.2**. I am using the **[fabric](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabric) (Javascript HTML5 canvas library)** library which is part of my problem.

#### Working, but incomplete solution

First I defined the variable just in `mounted()` which worked fine for all the functions called with this variable inside `mounted()`

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas", {
    isDrawingMode: true
});
```

#### Not working solution

Then, since I also wanted to use this variable inside `methods:` I put the content of `var canvas` inside the `data()` property like this:

```
data() {
    return {
      canvas: new fabric.Canvas("canvas", { isDrawingMode: true }),
      canvasControlBar: {
        color: "#29066b"
      }
    };
  },
```

In `methods:` I then used this line of code:

```
clearCanvas() {
    this.canvas.clear();
}
```

The console.log for both, `canvas.clear()` inside `mounted()` and `this.canvas.clear()` are the same except that chrome console display them slightly different.

I expect to use a variable defined as `new fabric.Canvas("canvas", { isDrawingMode: true })` in both, `mounted()` and `methods:`.

#### Whole Code

[Whole code at Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WVjqRK)

#### Console Logs

1. First log is from inside `mounted()` with `console.log(canvas.clear());`
2. Second log is from inside `data:` with `console.log(this.canvas.clear());`
   [image: Console logs in Chrome]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use computed property instead of data

Instead of storing `var canvas` inside `data()`, I stored it inside `computed:`. Therefore, I used the following code:

```
computed: {
    canvas() {
      return new fabric.Canvas("canvas", { isDrawingMode: true });
    }
  },
```

In `methods:` I then used:

```
this.canvas.clear();
```

[See the whole updated code on Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xvrxoR?editors=0010)